# How to filter the list based on the value of a key from JsonArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, lambda, collections

How can I filter a list based on the values of the `JSONArray`?

`JSONArray` has the elements which is in simple json structure with key and values.

`JSONArray` is from the package `org.json` and using this dependency

```
             <dependency>
               <groupId>org.json</groupId>
               <artifactId>json</artifactId>
               <version>20180130</version>
            </dependency>
```

The string response I get when I hit an endpoint is parsed in this way

```
   String response = [{"ID": 1,"updatedAt": "2019-04-12T09:09:48"},{"ID": 2,"updatedAt": "2019-04-12T09:09:48"}      
   JSONArray jsonArray =  new JSONArray(response)
```

The list I want to filter consists of list of json strings `List<String> eventDataSetList`

Now how can I filter the list using the value of key `ID` from `jsonArray` in a better way than this?

Here is what I have done so far, But I really don't want to use nested loop:

```
Map<Object, String> filteredEvents = new HashMap<>();
for (String event : eventDataSetList) {
    for (Object obj : jsonArray) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        if (event.contains(jsonObject.getString("ID"))) {
            filteredEvents.put(jsonObject, event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type `jsonArray`? Is it an array, or a List?

Comment: @samuel Phillipp it is an array. Sorry for missing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java Stream API with this:

```
Map<JSONObject, String> filteredEvents = StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), false).map(o -> (JSONObject) o)
        .flatMap(o -> eventDataSetList.stream().filter(e -> e.contains(o.getString("ID"))).map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(o, e)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

This creates a Stream, which iterates over all elements in your JSON array and finds all events matching the condition `event.contains(jsonObject.getString("ID"))`. Finally they are collected to a Map.

Comment: Arrays.stream(jsonArray) does not work. jsonArray cannot be streamed. Other than that thanks for the help

Comment: Can you please share the type of `jsonArray`? Please add that to your question.

Comment: added further details in  the question. Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer, but you should maybe use `o.get("ID").toString()` instead of `o.getString("ID")` because that has thrown an `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["ID"] not a string.` for the string you shared.